# What is meant by the Poincaré Index Theorem?

Tags: differential-topology, dynamical-systems, vector-fields, topological-vector-spaces

Section 3.12 (pg. 299) of Lawrence Perko's *Differential Equations and Dynamical Systems* ([3rd edition](https://www-users.cse.umn.edu/%7Escheel/teaching/8501-fall18/perko.pdf)) on index theory states "It is one of the most interesting facts of the index theory that the index of the surface $S$, $I_{\mathbf{f}}(S)$, is independent of of the vector field $\mathbf{f}$... This result is the famous Poincaré Index Theorem."

It then gives the formula for the index which is defined as

$    I_{\mathbf{f}}(C) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \oint_C
\frac{PdQ - QdP}{P^2 + Q^2}$

for some vector field $\mathbf{f} = \begin{pmatrix} P(x,y) \\ Q(x,y)\end{pmatrix}$

Example 1 (starting on the same page) says:

Let $C$ be the circle of radius one, centered at the origin, and let us compute the index of $C$ relative to the vector fields

$\mathbf{f}(x) = \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y\end{pmatrix} \quad \mathbf{g}(x) = \begin{pmatrix} -x \\ -y\end{pmatrix} \quad \mathbf{h}(x) = \begin{pmatrix} -y \\x \end{pmatrix} \quad \mathbf{k}(x) = \begin{pmatrix} x \\-y \end{pmatrix}$

the results being

$I_{\mathbf{f}}(C) = 1, \quad I_{\mathbf{g}}(C) = 1, \quad I_{\mathbf{h}}(C) = 1, \quad I_{\mathbf{k}}(C) = -1$

Doesn't this violate what was just stated in the Poincaré index theorem? That is, it looks to me that the index of the same surface $C$ is not independent of the vector field since $I_{\mathbf{k}}(C)$ is not equal to the others. Is there some qualification to the theorem that I'm missing or something I haven't understood? I am working on solving for the index of $C$ relative to a more complicated vector field and also seing that it is not equal to 1.

Comment: The index theorem is a statement about smooth vector fields on _compact_ surfaces (or manifolds). In the plane, as these examples show, the "total index" is not an invariant.

Comment: There is something missing, it is invariant under continuous changes of $f$ (and also $S$) that avoid the zero-vector as value (on $S$). $f$, $g$, $h$ are rotations of each other, can thus be connected by a continuous path of rotations. $k$ is a reflection of $f$ or $g$, there is no continuous path of movements of the tangent plane that connects it to the others.

Comment: The index of the surface is the *sum* of all the local indices at the singular points of the vector field. For a compact surface, the answer is the Euler characteristic of the surface.